# Ternary Search Tree find max word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a maximum function so that it finds that longest word in the Ternary Search Tree and prints it.

This is what I have done so far. I have words in the tree such as "canvas", "cats" "van" but it prints None any way.

```
def maximum(self):
    if self.root == None:
        return 0
    ptr = self.root
    self.maxLengthTST(ptr)

def maxLengthTST(self,ptr): 
    if ptr.left == None:
        return
    if ptr.next == None:
        return
    if ptr.right == None:
        return
    return max(self.maxLengthTST(ptr.left),  self.maxLengthTST(ptr.next)+1, self.maxLengthTST(ptr.right)); 

def max( a, b, c):
    max = 0
    if a >= b and a >= c:
        max = a
    elif b >= a and b >= c:
        max = b
    else:
        max = c
    return max
```

Comment: `maximum` does not return anything.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately this question is _off-topic_ because this site is for reviewing **working** code. Please [take the tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up at our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). When the code works then feel free to [edit] the post to include it for a review.